# SQL query for category hierarchy validations

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I need to add validation on category creation.

- CASE 1: `parentId` should be valid if supplied
- CASE 2: `name` of sibling could not be duplicated

I have this table `categories`:

```
    id  | parentId  | name  
   -----|-----------|------
    1   | NULL      | CatA
    2   | 1         | CatA.1
```

(Note: My parent child hierarchy can go up-to nth level)

Now in the above scenario what should not be allowed is:

1. I cannot provide an invalid `parentId`
2. I cannot create a category with name: CatA where parentId = null
3. I cannot create a category where name: CatA.1 where parentId = 1

Now I am in a nodejs so I need to return these 2 validations errors:

1. The provided parentId is invalid
2. Duplicate name detected

Now I want to achieve this using a single optimized SQL query.
I can use if else statements later on the base of query response.
But for me it is really important that I use single query and that query should be as optimized as possible.

What I tried so far is:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 parentId,
    name,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN name = 'CatA.2' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
    ) sortOrder
FROM
    catagories
WHERE
    parentId = 1
ORDER BY
    sortOrder DESC
```

Now the issue with  my query is that it doesn't cover all the scenarios.

Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: its an  sql querry

Comment: I am running this query in ms sql server

Comment: In your table definition make parentID a foreign key of ID.  That will take care of constraint #1.  Then add a unique, compound, nullable index on parentID & name.  That should take care of constraints 2 & 3.  You will have to add entries top-down and remove them bottom-up which can get to be a pain.

Comment: Actually I can not change database structure, I need to achieve this using query and if else statements

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with single query is that you have two cases which have different validation needs:

1. Provided parent_id is null
2. Provided parent_id is not null

Isn't it easier to write two queries and call the correct one from nodejs?

Query 1: Select rows where parent_id is null and name matches passed name. If it doesn't return any rows then all is OK, otherwise return error. Note that code should be parent_id IS NULL and not parent_id = NULL

Query 2: The query you wrote. If it doesn't return, then parent_id is invalid. If it returns and sortorder = 1 then you have a duplicate, otherwise all is well

Comment: Actually I don’t have the permission to write single query, of course that would have been much easier, i need to achieve this via single query

Comment: Why not. does the company pay per number of characters?

Comment: That’s hilarious. Actually they think why to open multiple connections to database when it can be done via single

Comment: But you will still have one call only. nodejs has code like: if (parentID == null) call query1; else call query2;